# google extensions document asynchronous registration instructions conflict

Tags: google-chrome-extension

google extensions mentioned in the documentation: Do not register listeners asynchronously, as they will not be properly triggered.

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages#listeners

[image]

But it violated the description in the example, which is very contradictory.

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declarativeContent#event-onPageChanged

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's not contradictory in this particular case because `chrome.declarativeContent` registration is stored inside Chrome's internal preferences in order to process the rules internally in its own internal network listeners without even running any JavaScript, which is the purpose of all declarative API of extensions as switching contexts between JS and native runtime is slow.

- same goes for all API with `declarative` in their name
- same goes for `chrome.contextMenus` as Chrome builds the menu internally